# PHP - Group rows by the first letter

Tags: php, mysql, string, select, indexing

I am trying to display some elements from my database in an organized and clear way and I can't find a proper solution. Let's say I have these rows in db: apple, anchor, beat, cover, classmate, curtain... I need to display them like this:

```
A
apple
anchor

B
beat

C
cover
classmate
curtain
```

So there are separate divs with separate classes based on the first letter of the word. I can create a class with a mysql query to select names like $char, where $char is a parameter, and repeat the class by A-Z time... But I don't like this, as there is too much manual work. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Do you want the list to be entirely in alphabetical order? Or just grouped by first letter? Do you care if letters that don't start any of your words don't show up as headers? For example, if you don't have any words that start with 'x', do you still need to see an 'X' category with nothing underneath, or should it skip from 'W' to 'Y'?

The exact implementation may vary based on the answers to those questions. Here's a solution that should display the list entirely in alpha order, skipping categories with no words in them. (Not sure what kind of markup you want; this is pretty bare bones).

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT col FROM table ORDER BY col");
$lastFoundLetter = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    //get the first letter of the current record
    $firstLetter = substr($row['col'], 0, 1);
    if ($firstLetter != $lastFoundLetter) {
        //you've started a new letter category
        if ($lastFoundLetter != '') {
            //if there's a real value in $lastFoundLetter, we need to close the previous div 
            echo "</div>";
        }
        echo "<div id='" . strtoupper($firstLetter) . "'>";
        echo strtoupper($firstLetter) . "<br/>";
        $lastFoundLetter = $firstLetter;
    }
    echo $row['col']. "<br/>";
}
//close the last div
if ($lastFoundLetter != '') {
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alphabetize them, then as you are printing, keep track of which letter you're on.  When you find a new letter, print a new header before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a single query to read all the words (sorted, of course) into a PHP array.  Then with a bit of PHP code you could pull them out of the array, insert the leading letters 'A', 'B', as necessary.

Comment: Thanks Jay! Your suggestion helpped me. I used a for to go through the array and check if the first letter of the item is different than the first letter of the previous item.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work.

```
<?php
$words = $db->query("select word from table order by word")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
$groups = array();

foreach($words as $word) {
    $groups[$word[0]][] = $word;
}

foreach(range('a', 'z') as $c) {
    echo $c . "\n";
    foreach($words[$c] as $word) {
        echo $word . "\n";
    }
}
```